# NullPointerException when adding Object to ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I'm very new to Java and have been trying to set-up an ArrayList **CustomerList** that takes object **Customer**, where **Customer** has attributes from class **IAddress**. When calling the **.add** method in my main code however, I am given a *NullPointerException* error, which I assume is being given because my method isn't receiving anything to add to the ArrayList. I thought it was an issue with the attributes being initialised to empty strings, but when editing them to contain some information, the error still occured.

The ArrayList **CustomerList**

```
public class CustomerList {

public ArrayList<Customer> Clients;

public CustomerList() {
    Clients = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void add(Customer src) {        
    Clients.add(src);
}

public void remove(Customer src) {
    Clients.remove(src);
}

public void Display(JTextArea jClientsTextArea) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Clients.size(); i++) {
        Clients.get(i).Display(jClientsTextArea);
    }
}
}
```

Receives **Customer** from this class

```
public class Customer {

private String FirstName;
private String Surname;
private IAddress HomeAddress;
public String DOB;

public Customer() {
    FirstName = "";
    Surname = "";
    DOB = "01/01/1900";
    HomeAddress = new IAddress();

    public void Display(javax.swing.JTextArea jAddressTextArea) {
    jAddressTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    jAddressTextArea.append("First Name: " + FirstName + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("Surname: " + Surname + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("DOB:" + DOB + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("Street: " + HomeAddress.getStreet() + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("House Name: " + HomeAddress.getHouseName() + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("House Number: " + HomeAddress.getHouseNo() + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("Area: " + HomeAddress.getArea() + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("Postcode: " + HomeAddress.getPostCode() + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("Town: " + HomeAddress.getTown() + "\n");
    jAddressTextArea.append("Country: " + HomeAddress.getCountry() + "\n");
}


    public void Edit(String strfirstname, String strsurname, String strDOB, String strStreet, String strHouseName, String strHouseNo, String strHouseArea, String strPostCode, String strTown, String strCountry) {
    FirstName = strfirstname;
    Surname = strsurname;
    DOB = strDOB;
    HomeAddress.setStreet(strStreet);
    HomeAddress.setHouseName(strHouseName);
    HomeAddress.setHouseNo(strHouseNo);
    HomeAddress.setArea(strHouseArea);
    HomeAddress.setPostCode(strPostCode);
    HomeAddress.setTown(strTown);
    HomeAddress.setCountry(strCountry);
}
}
```

Which receives attributes from **IAddress**

```
public class IAddress {

private String Name;
private String Street;
private String HouseNo;
private String HouseName;
private String Area;
private String PostCode;
private String Town;
private String Country;

public IAddress() {
    Name = "";
    Street = "";
    HouseNo = "";
    HouseName = "";
    Area = "";
    PostCode = "";
    Town = "";
    Country = "";
}



public void setName(String strName) {
    Name = strName;
}

public void setStreet(String strStreet) {
    Street = strStreet;
}

public void setHouseNo(String strHouseNo) {
    HouseNo = strHouseNo;
}

public void setHouseName(String strHouseName) {
    HouseName = strHouseName;
}

public void setArea(String strArea) {
    Area = strArea;
}

public void setPostCode(String strPostCode) {
    PostCode = strPostCode;
}

public void setTown(String strTown) {
    Town = strTown;
}

public void setCountry(String strCountry) {
    Country = strCountry;
}

}
```

I've been banging my head against this problem for hours and am ready for it to be something stupidly simple. Thank you.

Comment: Don't assume. Read and post the exception stack trace, and draw conclusions.

Comment: And show us the code calling all this please

Comment: Duplicate (can't vote for now) -> [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Could you post the exception (the full stacktrace)?

Comment: It's likely the `Customer` you're passing to `add()` has not been initialized. Could you share your main method as well?

Comment: The Display method is defined inside the Customer constructor. That's illegal in java.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I don't think your question is prohibited, but the reason for the down votes is that it's not entirely on-topic. Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also, I recommend finding a good resource that will help you with Java code conventions. Like English grammar rules, they're not not important. (For example, method names and variable names should generally start with a lower case letter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above the only reason why calling `myCustomerList.add(...)` could throw is that `myCustomerList` itself is `null`. This is because the `Clients` inside it is initialized in the constructor, and never set to `null` again. The value of `src` does not matter as well - the call to `Clients.add(src)` would succeed even if `src` is `null`.

You need to make sure that in your `main` you do initialize your customer list, like this:

```
CustomerList list = new CustomerList();
```

Comment: Was exactly this problem, thank you so much. Sorry for not posting the full error log and main code, this is a small part of a much bigger project I've been working on and I didn't have the time to cut out the relevant section of code.